# Как правильно декодировать тем письма в javax.mail.Message

Tags: java, javamail

Всем привет!

```
javax.mail.Message message

String sbj = message.getSubject();
```

> // sbj = "=?windows-1251?Q?=CE=E1=ED=EE=E2=EB=E5=ED=ED=FB=E9 =EF=F0=E0=E9=F1 =CE=CE?= =?windows-1251?Q?=CE \"=D2=C4 =D4=EE=F0=E0=D4=E0=F0=EC\" =CA=E0=E7=E0=ED=FC?="

Такая проблема не со всеми письмами, а только выборочно.
Если письмо пересылаю себе на почту, то в веб морде mail.ru тема отображается нормально.

Подскажите пожалуйста как декодировать такую тему?

Answer (score 3):

Как раз вчера делал такое только на php, извини что не могу помочь на твоем языке, но постараюсь объяснять понятно.

> =?windows-1251?Q?=CE=E1=ED=EE=E2=EB=E5=ED=ED=FB=E9 =EF=F0=E0=E9=F1 =CE=CE?=

в этой строке в начале идет информация о шифровании и кодировке, дальше текст
`=?windows-1251?Q?` (это информация о кодировке и шифровании)

`=CE=E1=ED=EE=E2=EB=E5=ED=ED=FB=E9 =EF=F0=E0=E9=F1 =CE=CE` (это само сообщение)
сначала нужно дешифровать, `Q` значит что это `quoted_printable` (загуглиш как в java это дешифровать), еще бывает `B` это `base64`.
После меняешь кодировку из указанной windows-1251 на свою.